# Add onrightclick property to canvas with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, event-handling, dojo

I am trying to add onrightclick property to my canvas like this:

```
canvas.onclick = function(evnt) {
    doSomethingClick();
}

canvas.onrightclick = function(evnt) {
    doSomethingRightClick();              
}
```

The code is simple and I do the same for 'onclick' and 'onrightclick'. The onclick part is working, but when I right click I get browser right click. How can I override the browser right click as intended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

probably you're looking for [`oncontextmenu`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.oncontextmenu)

```
<canvas id="cnv" width="200" height="200"></canvas>

var cnv = document.getElementById('cnv');
cnv.oncontextmenu = function() {
   alert('right click');  
   return false; 
}
```

example fiddle (tried on Fx12/MacOS) : http://jsfiddle.net/Jk3Jx/1

Comment: Worked in Opera 11. Annoying that the menu opens after the alert tho.

Comment: @OptimusCrime I forgot the `return false` on the fiddle. Now it works on Opera 11.64 and Chrome 19

Comment: You are right, it works perfect now. Nice catch too. I never knew about this. +1'd

Answer (score 0):

```
dojo.connect(canvas, 'onclick', function(e) {
  if (dojo.mouse.isRight(e)) {
    ...
  }
});
```

If you want a context menu using, dojo widgets, then check out

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/Menu.html